# How to determine at what point regeneration of a signal is necessary?

Tags: signal-processing, noise, attenuation

I have a "homework" question that has raised some doubts in my mind about when regeneration of a signal is necessary and whether it can be determined from a given SNR (signal to noise ratio) alone **or whether there is some other margin above/below which regeneration is deemed necessary.** For completeness I am presenting the question and my calculations, but really I am after some answers to the above expressed doubts.

PROBLEM: "A digital optical fibre system has an input power of 10mW and a SNR of 60 dB. The ambient noise power is 1 x 10-14 W. (a) Calculate the minimum output power required before regeneration of the signal is necessary."

In the context of this problem, I presume the SNR of 60 dB is the margin at which regeneration is required. Greater attenuation of the signal would lead to a reduction in the SNR.

```
SNR = 10Log(Ps/Pn)

60dB = 10Log(Ps/1 * 10^-14)

6 = Log(Ps/1 * 10^-14)

10^6 = Ps / 1 * 10^-14

Ps = 10^6 * 1 * 10^-14  

Ps = 1 x 10^-8 = 10 nW
```

Based on these calculations, I might then conclude that any further attenuation of the output signal (making it less than 10 nW) would make regeneration necessary.

Comment: Re, "...the margin at which regeneration is required." Required by whom? This sounds more like an engineering problem than a physics problem. I am not an expert in information theory, or signal processing, or any kind of communication system, but I would have guessed that different applications have different tolerance thresholds for noise.

Comment: @solomon slow Agreed - I believe that different applications will have different thresholds. Perhaps someone here might know that if a SNR is specified then it defines a point beyond which regeneration is required?